# Всем привет)).Поле cost должно при создании автоматически заполняться по формуле стоимость = опыт * 100 000 / лет.Но поле exp равно 0. Что делать

Tags: java, spring-boot

Вот код:

```
 public void setCost(long cost) {
            cost=1;
            long yer = getYears();
            long exp = getExperience();
            long cost1 = (exp*100000)/yer;
            this.cost = cost+exp;
        }
```

Когда храню игрока:

```
     {
    
             
             "name":"Oleg",
             "experience":5,
             "years":20,
             "teamDTO":{
                 "id":9
             }
        }
```

Получаю вот это:

```
{
    "id": 76,
    "name": "Oleg",
    "years": 20,
    "experience": 5,
    "cost": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "teamDTO": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Rostov",
        "country": "Russia",
        "budget": 150000,
        "rate": 9
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну если размышлять логически, то setCost это не создание. Вам нужен конструктор видимо, а не сетер.

Comment: для начала неплохо бы показать весь код класса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаете экземпляр player и вызываете setCost до того как в экземпляр записали Experience.

```
player.setExperience(playerDTO.getExperience()); выполняйте перед player.setCost(playerDTO.getCost());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void setCost(Long cost) {           
        long yer = getYears();
        long exp = getExperience();
        this.cost = cost + (exp*100000)/yer;            
    }
```

Может так должен выглядеть Ваш метод?
А что должно быть если exp равно 0?
if(exp==0) exp=1L;

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы при создании экземпляра класса автоматически выполнялся метод setCost? тогда объявите его в конструкторе класса

Comment: Ну или в сервисе при посте вызывать метод setCost экземпляра класса

Comment: Он сохраняется. getYears работает, а getExperience нет

Comment: Вот мой сервіс:
@Override
    public Player map(PlayerDTO playerDTO) {
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setId(playerDTO.getId());
        player.setName(playerDTO.getName());
        player.setYears(playerDTO.getYears());
        player.setCost(playerDTO.getCost());
        player.setTotal(playerDTO.getTotal());
        player.setExperience(playerDTO.getExperience());
        Team team = teamService.getOne(playerDTO.getTeamDTO().getId());
        player.setTeam(team);
        return player;
    }